# How can I combine preventDefault with Timeout in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-cli

How to do to allow a link to be deactivated 1500ms before I can click on it again? I want to be able a click every 1500ms and not nonstop. I tried something like this and without success. I don't want to use via CSS pointer-events, i want combine somehow preventdefault into my code.

```
<router-link :to="item.path" @click="blockedLinkOnClick(e)">{{ item.name }}</router-link>
```

And my method:

```
blockedLinkOnClick(e) {
  setTimeout(() => e.preventDefault(), 1500);
}
```

Comment: even without setTimeout, preventDefault won't prevent navigation.  try programmatic navigation within your method, i.e. [router.push()](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html) instead of using `router-link`, then you'll be able to [throttle](https://www.google.com/search?q=js+how+to+throttle) the function and prevent navigation.

Comment: I can change <router-link> to normal <a> tag, it will help?

Comment: yes, just so long as you dont add the `href` property.  the `router.push()` inside your method should handle the navigation instead.

Comment: Can u give me a example please? im not so good in this, still learning. With router.push or not, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way

`<router-link :to="item.path" :event="!isBlocked ? 'click' : ''">{{ item.name }}</router-link>`

```
isBlocked = false;
    
clickable() {
    if (this.isBlocked)
    {
        setTimeout(() => this.isBlocked = false, 1500);
    }
    else
    {
        this.isBlocked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: No error, but it doesn't work. Probably some typos in your code i quess.

Comment: yeah you are right, will look at it tommorow

Comment: sure i will wait

Comment: what if you would use a button instead of link? It would be easier to disable it and you can send redirect by this.$route.push('/'), because v-btn has the :disabled attribute and <a> and router-link does not

Answer (score 0):

In the template, we added a class of **blocked** to the router-link when **isLinkActive** is **false**. You can style this class however you like to visually indicate that the link is not currently active.

So, like this:

```
<template>
  <router-link :to="item.path" @click="blockedLinkOnClick(item.path)" :class="{ 'blocked': !isLinkActive }">{{ item.name }}</router-link>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      isLinkActive: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    blockedLinkOnClick(path) {
      if (this.isLinkActive) {
        this.isLinkActive = false;
        this.$router.push(path);
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.isLinkActive = true;
        }, 1500);
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```